# How do I loop through URLs with Selenium for scraping

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

The following is the code I have so far to scrape from https://n.rivals.com/state_rankings/2021/alabama.
I want the code to loop through the address with replacing all the states where alabama is. Ideally, I would also like to be able to change the year for future use. What am I doing wrong with how i defined url and year/state1?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

TIMEOUT = 5

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(TIMEOUT)

url = f"https://n.rivals.com/state_rankings/{year}/{state1}"
year = "2021"
state1 = "alabama"

try:
    driver.get(url)
except TimeoutException:
    pass

first_names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('first-name')
first_names = [name.text for name in first_names]

last_names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('last-name')
last_names = [name.text for name in last_names]

for first, last in zip(first_names, last_names):
    print(first, last)

player_positions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pos')
player_positions = [position.text for position in player_positions]

for position in player_positions:
    print(position)

data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="break-text ng-binding ng-scope"]')
for d in data:
    location, highschool = d.text.strip().split('\n')
    city, state = location.split(',')
    print(city)
    print(state)
    print(highschool)

commit_status = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('school-name')
commit_status = [commit.text for commit in commit_status]

for commit in commit_status:
    print(commit)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the variables before you refer to them like so:

```
year = "2021"
state1 = "alabama"
url = f"https://n.rivals.com/state_rankings/{year}/{state1}"
```

Then to make it loop for many states, you would do the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

TIMEOUT = 5

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(TIMEOUT)

def rivals_scrape(state, year):
    url = f"https://n.rivals.com/state_rankings/{year}/{state}"

    try:
        driver.get(url)
    except TimeoutException:
        pass

    first_names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('first-name')

    ... rest of code ...

    for commit in commit_status:
        print(commit)

states = ["alabama", "georgia","texas"]

for state in states:
    rivals_scrape(state, "2021")

driver.close()
```

Comment: Do I have to define state and year before the first loop? Or does the order not matter?

Comment: This example is a little confusing in terms of order due to the function. The function `def rivals_scrape` needs to be made first since you have to define it before you use it. Then, the states are defined. Finally, each state is passed in the function alongside the year. Coding the function acts a placeholder till it's actually called in the line `rivals_scrape(state, "2021")`. So, states and years are defined before they are used in the function.